# Join two matrices as in left_join in R

Tags: data, r, join

I have two data sets. I would like to join them left_join function of R [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/join)

```
d1={{1, 2.42}, {2, 1.58}, {3, 2.54}, {4, 1.48}, {5, 0.877}, {6, 
  2.65}, {7, 1.82}, {8, 2.22}, {9, 2.62}, {10, 1.4}, {11, 2.16}, {12, 
  1.91}, {13, 1.45}, {14, 2.02}, {15, 1.59}, {16, 1.5}, {17, 
  1.55}, {18, 1.7}, {19, 1.95}, {20, 1.53}, {21, 1.5}, {22, 
  1.94}, {23, 1.53}, {24, 1.11}, {25, 2.35}, {26, 1.35}, {27, 
  1.98}, {28, 1.81}, {30, 1.9}, {31, 1.81}, {32, 1.68}, {33, 
  1.54}, {34, 1.4}, {35, 2.2}, {36, 3.28}, {37, 2.05}, {61, 
  2.25}, {63, 3.83}, {64, 3.4}, {66, 2.41}, {69, 2.18}, {71, 
  3.64}, {75, 2.13}, {86, 4.53}, {87, 2.77}, {88, 2.97}, {89, 
  1.95}, {90, 0.51}, {91, 3.86}, {92, 3.96}, {93, 3.95}, {94, 
  2.38}, {95, 4.25}, {96, 1.48}, {97, 4.03}, {98, 4.45}, {99, 
  2.54}, {100, 2.56}, {101, 1.83}, {102, 1.69}, {103, 2.44}, {104, 
  2.65}, {105, 1.72}, {106, 1.49}, {107, 1.73}, {108, 1.84}, {109, 
  1.61}, {110, 1.42}, {111, 2.78}, {112, 1.36}, {113, 1.77}, {114, 
  1.22}, {115, 2.01}, {116, 1.65}, {117, 2.71}, {118, 1.72}, {119, 
  2.52}, {120, 1.87}, {121, 2.66}, {122, 2.66}, {123, 2.43}, {124, 
  2.24}, {125, 3.12}, {126, 2.64}, {127, 5.76}, {128, 1.87}, {129, 
  4.4}, {130, 4.73}, {131, 1.82}, {132, 2.65}, {133, 5.22}, {134, 
  2.6}, {135, 4}, {136, 3.42}, {137, 3.08}, {138, 1.84}, {139, 
  1.6}, {140, 2.12}, {141, 1.58}, {142, 1.98}, {143, 2.25}, {144, 
  3.2}, {145, 1.82}, {146, 2.16}, {147, 5.69}, {148, 2.32}};
d2={{1, 4.24}, {2, 3.16}, {3, 3.86}, {4, 2.67}, {5, 2.64}, {6, 2.82}, {7,
   2.38}, {8, 2.93}, {9, 2.38}, {10, 2.81}, {11, 4.21}, {12, 
  3.96}, {14, 3.27}, {15, 3.77}, {16, 3.86}, {17, 3.41}, {18, 
  3.4}, {19, 4.11}, {20, 2.73}, {21, 2.64}, {22, 4.05}, {23, 
  3.59}, {24, 2.25}, {25, 3.23}, {26, 2.96}, {27, 3.07}, {28, 
  2.81}, {30, 2.96}, {31, 2.8}, {32, 4.59}, {33, 2.9}, {34, 
  2.65}, {35, 3.51}, {36, 4.85}, {37, 3.58}, {61, 4.02}, {63, 
  6.39}, {64, 6}, {66, 4.25}, {69, 5.41}, {71, 4.74}, {75, 3.83}, {86,
   6.09}, {87, 6.66}, {88, 4.47}, {89, 3.07}, {90, 2.23}, {91, 
  7.31}, {92, 6.21}, {93, 7.7}, {94, 3.68}, {95, 6.45}, {96, 
  3.85}, {97, 6.3}, {98, 5.05}, {99, 3.9}, {100, 4.86}, {126, 
  5.89}, {127, 9.31}, {128, 3.8}, {129, 7.21}, {130, 7.42}, {131, 
  4.06}, {132, 4.48}, {133, 7.06}, {134, 5}, {135, 7.9}, {136, 
  6}, {137, 5.6}};
```

Here is my solution. It is a little bit ugly. Is there a nicer way to do this?

```
d22 = (Join @@ {d1, 
       Table[If[MemberQ[d1[[All, 1]], i] == True, 
         Nothing, {i, Missing}], {i, 148}]} // Sort)[[All, 2]];

d33 = (Join @@ {d2, 
       Table[If[MemberQ[d2[[All, 1]], i] == True, 
         Nothing, {i, Missing}], {i, 148}]} // Sort)[[All, 2]];

(mm = Transpose@{d22, d33})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ResourceFunction["TableSet"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TableSet/).

With `ds1` and `ds2` has in OP then

```
tableset = ResourceFunction["TableSet"];
tsd1 = tableset[{"pos", "val1"}, d1]
tsd2 = tableset[{"pos", "val2"}, d2]
```

> [image]

```
leftjoined = JoinAcross[tsd1, tsd2, "pos", "Left"]
```

> [image]

Values with

```
leftjoined["Data"] // Short
```

> ```
> {{1,2.42,4.24},{2,1.58,3.16},<<102>>,{147,5.69,Null},{148,2.32,Null}}
> ```

or

```
TableForm[leftjoined]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is that like a dataframe but with better performance than Dataset? I've been looking for something like this for a while.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes. It has a much smaller memory footprint than `Dataset`. There is a comparison in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know R, but if this is a typical left join, you could use JoinAcross. First we need to add some structure to the data. It looks like the first element is being used as a key.

```
assoc1 = AssociationThread[{"key", "value1"} -> #] & /@ d1;
assoc2 = AssociationThread[{"key", "value2"} -> #] & /@ d2;
```

As an example, the first element of assoc1 is

```
<|"key" -> 1, "value1" -> 2.42|>
```

Now we can use JoinAcross:

```
joined = JoinAcross[assoc1, assoc2, "key", "Left"]
```

As an example, the first element of joined is

```
<|"key" -> 1, "value1" -> 2.42, "value2" -> 4.24|>
```

An example where the key was missint from assoc2 is

```
<|"key" -> 13, "value1" -> 1.45, "value2" -> Missing["Unmatched"]|>
```

If you want to destructure this to get back to simple lists without keys (like your mm), you could do this:

```
Values[joined][[All, 2 ;;]]
```